# Inserting nodes into a tree Breadth First

Tags: java, tree, breadth-first-search

I am trying to generate tree with a breadth first form of insertion.
I have tried to do this by generating a List with all the elements in the Tree in breadth first order. Then in my insertNode method I check if the node needs children with a method called needsChildren(), and if it does I add the node i am inserting into the tree in the leftmost spot possible.

if I call 
insertNode(10)
insertNode(8)
insertNode(20)
insertNode(5)
insertNode(29)
insertNode(50)

The tree generated should be

```
          10
    8           20

5      29    50
```

and so on...

This solution is not working and I am not quite sure why. I think it is possible that my generateList is not working properly, but I have checked the last list printed and it seems to be right.

Is there a better way to do this, or is there a problem in my code that I can't find. Any help is really appreciated.

This is my TreeNode Class:

```
private static class TreeNode<T> {

    public T data;
    public TreeNode<T> left;
    public TreeNode<T> right;

    public TreeNode(T d) {
                    data = d;
                    left = null;
                    right = null;
    }
}
```

My insertNode method:

```
public void insertNode(T d) { 

    if(root==null){
        root= new TreeNode<T>(d);             
    }

    genList(root);

    if(needsChildren(nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0))){
        if(nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0).left==null){
            nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0).left= new TreeNode<T>(d);
        }else{
            nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0).right= new TreeNode<T>(d);
        }
    }else{
        while(!needsChildren(nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0))){
            nodesThatNeedChildren.remove(0);

        }
        System.out.println(nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0).data);


        if(nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0).left==null){
            nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0).left = new TreeNode<T>(d);
        }else{
            nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0).right = new TreeNode<T>(d);
        }
    }


}
```

My method to check if the node needs children:

```
public boolean needsChildren(TreeNode<T> node){
    if(node.left==null || node.right ==null){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And my method that generates the list of all nodes in the tree:

```
public void genList(TreeNode<T> root) {
    //generate new List each time
    nodesThatNeedChildren.clear();
    nodesThatNeedChildren.add(root);

    //generate new Queue each time genList is called
    tempQueue.clear();
    tempQueue.add(root);

    while(!tempQueue.isEmpty()){

        TreeNode<T> node = tempQueue.remove(0);

        if(node.left != null){ 
            tempQueue.add(node.left);
            nodesThatNeedChildren.add(node.left);
        }     

        if(node.right != null){
            tempQueue.add(node.right);
            nodesThatNeedChildren.add(node.right);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the data is already in "breadth first order" then just an ordinary insert into a tree should work.  I think I worked this out once and it's fine.  Are you sure your insert method works for normal data too?  I'd try to get that working first, might be a simple programming error.

Comment: One thing on your example data, the 29 should be on the right node, not the left as you have shown it.  To search for 29, any normal search method would go right at 10 (the root) and never find the 29.  That bit has to be wrong.

Comment: @markspace The order in which I need to generate the tree is as I have shown. Inserting each node in the left most position possible on each level of the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find my mistake after a little bit of debugging. This issue was in my insertNode() method.

I was generating the firstNode I inserted twice into the tree.

this because I called

```
if(root==null){
    root= new TreeNode<T>(d);             
}
```

for the first node, but then did not break out of the method after instead the rest of the code was then called which was generating the first node twice. A simple else if statement solved the problem. The resolved code looks like this.

```
public void insertNode(T d) { 


    if(root==null){
        root= new TreeNode<T>(d); 
        size+=1;    

    }
    else if(root!=null){
        genList(root);
        if(needsChildren(nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0))){
            if(nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0).left==null){
                nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0).left= new TreeNode<T>(d);
                size+=1;
            }else{
                nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0).right= new TreeNode<T>(d);
                size+=1;
            }
        }else{
            while(!needsChildren(nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0))){
                nodesThatNeedChildren.remove(0);

            }

            if(nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0).left==null){
                nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0).left = new TreeNode<T>(d);
                size+=1;
            }else{
                nodesThatNeedChildren.get(0).right = new TreeNode<T>(d);
                size+=1;
            }
        }
    }




}
```